# SQL Developer missing a library

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, tnsnames

I'm fairly new to Oracle SQL developer. As I'm trying to make a new connection via TNS, I'm getting this error down below which I've been looking to solve for a while fruitlessly.

Error Message:

> Statut : échec -Echec du test : no ocijdbc18 in java.library.path

[image: Statut : échec -Echec du test : no ocijdbc18 in java.library.path]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming MySQL is a typo (You are using port 1521, which is the default port for Oracle database, also its giving you ODBC error, so I assume its an Oracle database. Remember that you can connect SQL developer to a MySQL database, so please clarify if you want to connect to a MySQL database rather than Oracle) your problem is due to lack of Oracle Data Base Connector driver (ODBC). From this [link](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/winx64-64-downloads.html) download the latest version of Oracle Instant client and install it on your machine. Then define `ORACLE_HOME` to the path of Instant client installation (To the actual installation folder, the one that contains folders like `bin`, `network` and so on) and restart SQL Developer, then you should be good to go.

P.S. : as @thatjeffsmith has mentioned correctly in the comments, it's not necessary to have Oracle Client and/or ODBC (or similar) drivers in order to connect to an Oracle database. Using `basic` as the connection type and adding the correct connection info would suffice. [This Article](https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/making-database-connections) in Oracle Magazine has extensively talked about the different connection types.

Comment: Change your connection type to basic. Put in the connection details,  use service not sid

Comment: You are right, mistake on the typo. I'm using oracle database. I have downloaded instant client already, but I didn't manage to install it as there were no executables in there. may you explain with the boring details on how to proceed after the download.

Comment: Unfortunately I use Linux so I can't check and test the Windows installation, but the detailed instructions can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/r-enterprise/1.5.1/oread/installing-oracle-database-instant-client.html)

Comment: @aLuViAn : Thanks buddy, helped me solve my long lasting problem; i just had to add a path in Environment variables (variable PATH), add a new one and link it to the instant client extracted file. Cheers

Comment: For anyone else reading this, you dont need a client to connect to Oracle..it's necessary in this case bc you're using the tns identifier instead of the alias-dropdown option

Comment: @thatjeffsmith you are right, with EZconnect connection string or similar methods, it's possible to connect without the client and/or the driver. I will update my answer based on this.